# Python create multi-dimensional dictionary using list comprehensions

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, valueerror

I have dictionary in the following format:

```
   dictionary = {'key' : ('value', row_number, col_number)}
```

I want that dictionary converted to below format:

```
   converted_dict = {'key' : {'row':row_number, 'col':col_number}}
```

By using the following code i am getting below error

```
   dict_list = [(key, dict([('row',value[1]), ('column',value[2])])) for 
                                               key, value in cleaned_dict]
   converted_dict = dict(dict_list)       



   ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you try to convert the dictionary to list when what you want is in fact dict. It seems you don't understand how to do dict comprehension. Try this approach:

```
converted_dict = {
   key: {'row': value[1], 'column': value[2]} for key, value in cleaned_dict.items()
}
```

Also note that if you want to iterate over both the keys and the values in a dictionary you should call `dictionary.items()` (like in the code above)

Comment: Thanks, It really helped me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dictionary comprehension:

```
dictionary = {'key' : ('value', 'row_number', 'col_number')}
>>> {k: {'row': row, 'col': col} for k, (_, row, col) in dictionary.items()}
{'key': {'row': 'row_number', 'col': 'col_number'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through dictionary only return nd no need of extra steps for convert list into dictionary. key,

So here we need pair of key and values so we need to use `dict.items`,

```
In [6]: lst = {'a':(0,1),'b':(2,1)}

In [7]: converted_dict = dict((key, dict([('row',value[0]), ('column',value[1])])) for key, value in lst.items())
Out[7]: {'a': {'column': 1, 'row': 0}, 'b': {'column': 1, 'row': 2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

...and yet another *dict-comprehension*.

```
converted_dict = {k : dict(zip(('row', 'column'), v[1:])) for k, v in dictionary.items()}
```

which for:

```
dictionary = {'a' : ('value', 1, 2), 'b' : ('value', 0, 0)}
```

returns:

```
{'a': {'row': 1, 'column': 2}, 'b': {'row': 0, 'column': 0}}
```

The only thing **wrong with your code** is that it is missing the `.items()`<sup>1</sup>. It had to be:

```
dict_list = [... for key, value in cleaned_dict.items()]
```

<sup>1.</sup> If you are using Python 2 you need `.iteritems()` instead.